# Using fgets to read from a file

Tags: c

A Small C question for you, appreciate your help:

A file's first line is:
"add A"
It has more lines beneath.

I'm reading the first line from the file using fgets:

```
char str [500];
fgets(str,sizeof(str),filePointer);
```

Since fgets stops at the newline char, I replace the unwanted newline char with '\0':

```
char *p;
if ((p = strchr(str, '\n')) != NULL)
  *p = '\0';
```

Now if I print str this way:

```
printf("DEBUG: str:=[%s]\n",str);
```

Why do I get a crappy output like this:

```
]EBUG: str:=[add A
```

and not:

```
DEBUG: str:=[add A]
```

??
Thanks!!

Comment: Look at `str` in the debugger. You will see something interesting.

Comment: or use `hexdump` to look at your output in hex. Or to look at your input in hex, for that matter.

Comment: Oh the Bill Gates infamous carriage return..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file likely uses `\r\n` line-endings  (aka. Windows line-endings) and you therefore left a trailing `\r` in.

Kill the `\r` as well and you should be done.

Comment: Is it me or Microsoft loves making stuff weird and uncompatible? e.g. carriage return, windows 8, windows explorer...

Comment: @Israel Windows does use \r\n for a technical reason. Back in the DOS days, there were different standards/conventions. MS-DOS uses the CR-LF convention, which is the standard was that printers used to use. And thus windows uses the \r\n for line break for backwards compatibility with DOS.

Comment: @CCInc Never thought about why they use it (since DOS). Old school printers... makes perfect sense. Thanks for this nugget of history.

Comment: @CCInc Yes but is there a reason for them not to drop this feature in these years? My windows 8 added this character.

Comment: @Israel Well, it's pretty much a standard now for windows to use \r\n. It would create compatibility issues with existing programs.